# Inline declaration of an internal table of string leads to type incompatibility

Tags: string, abap

Following an example given [here](https://answers.sap.com/answers/72386/view.html), I'm using the VALUE operator to declare and populate a table of string values:

```
DATA tab TYPE TABLE OF STRING.
tab = VALUE #( ( 'abc' ) ( 'xyz' ) )
```

SAP gives the following error message :

> "'abc'" and the row type of "TAB" are incompatible.

However, this works:

```
DATA tab TYPE TABLE OF STRING.
tab = VALUE #( ( conv string('abc') ) ( conv string('xyz') ) )
```

This is a version 2021 system.

What is causing this error ? Shouldn't a literal be recognized directly as a string ?

Comment: [in the help](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenconstructor_expression_value.htm) they give the hint to use CONV for overcoming this incompatibility: `The conversion operator CONV closes the gap where no elementary data objects can be constructed in operand positions using VALUE.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `'abc'` use `` `abc` `` and your problem will be solved.

`'abc'` is always interpreted as a `CHAR` type of the given length
`` `abc` `` however is interpreted as `STRING` type by the compiler, no need to cast.

Comment: You can also use the new string template syntax in this case (`|abc|`). It also results in a string and you can use one less notation in your code. I have heard people claim it has a performance penalty, but I doubt that because string templates get parsed during activation, not at runtime.

Comment: @Philipp At least when they got introduced there was a performance info within SLIN to not use them if they aren't used with embedded expressions due to performance penalties. No clue if that's still the case.